# How to find out, when and why and how a component's property is changed at runtime?

Tags: delphi, debugging, components, watch

I have a huge VCL Forms application in delphi and there is an option to display or hide a certain control (MyControl) on each form. Right now the traditional option is enabled, so MyControl should be hidden at runtime.
In Delphi Designer both Controls are visible. Every form is derived from a MyForm-class and in its OnCreate-Procedure the Visible-property of a MyControl (if available) is set to false (according to the traditional option enabled). This does work (as I can see with breaking points and watching expressions). For almost all forms this results in the MyControl not showing.

However for one certain form at some point the MyControl-component itself or any other part of the program sets the MyControls' visibility to true again. How do I find out where this happens?

I am using Delphi 10.1.

my approach:
I've tried to watch the visible-property through the watching-expressions-window using several breaking points. But of course the watching-expression is not available anywhere in the Code (myControl.Visible will only work if the breakingpoint is somewhere myControl is defined). I set a breaking-point anywhere I could evalute myControl.Visible but the magic seems to happen somewhere in between.
**So my question: is there some kind of a global variable name, so that I can evalute and watch the visible-property wherever the debugger pauses the program?**

a different approach:
I set a data- and an address-breakingpoint but they never fire. Only when I close the program they pause the program a few times.

Comment: Why not add a Visible property setter for your TMyControl and put a breakpoint in that?  Then, inspecting the call stack will show you what changed it?

Comment: Are you sure you even hide that control in the first place when you are starting your application? Also based on your description it seems that in most cases you want your control to not be visible. So wouldn't it be better to set it visibility to False during design time and then to True at runtime when the controll is actually needed. This way you don't need to have constructor for every form.

Comment: Debug the VCL and set a break point in the VCL code behind visible property setter.

Comment: If it is a wincontrol. you can put a breakpoint on the SetWindowPos call in TWinControl.CMShowingChanged with the conditon "self=someunit.someform.mycontrol". Check call stack for the reason when the program breaks.

Comment: *".. some kind of a global variable name .."* - Try "myunit.myform.mycontrol.visible".

Answer (score 1):

As advised in the comments, if this is your code you can modify the property to use a Setter and then set a breakpoint on the setter.  However if this is not your code and it simply exposes the variable (field) then changing the code to include a setter can be anywhere from triovial to impossible depending on what else needs to be recompiled when you make the change.

If this is your own custom component then you can redeclare an inherited property to use a setter.

If this is not your own custom component - you could make it a custom component and simply change the setter for the property.

You can set a memory breakpoint to alert you to when a memory location changes but your success with this may vary.

I encourage you to experiment with the conditions you can put on breakpoints, get the debugger to work for you.

Comment: I doubt whether "impossible" is correct:  the OP could simply put a setter in an interposer class.

Comment: I don't know a great deal about the internals of Delphi compiled code, but if you have compiled code (no source) that's accessing a property in a base class (a VCL control for example), writing an interposer class in your code will not change the bahaviour of the closed source code ... or will it?

Comment: Actually ignore my previous comment that I've deleted.  Although interposers can do things like adding property setters, there is a complication concerning how they interact with the streaming system a Delphi app uses to initialize forms.  If I can remind myself how to resolve it, I'll be back ...